# Textbox null control with script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox(it gets integer value) on my page and i set "0" to textboxes with this script at startup.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.myclass').each(function () {
            this.value = this.value || "0";
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also my textbox looks like:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Answers[i].Answer, new { @style = "width:45px; margin-left:10px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center;", @class="myclass" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Answers[i].Answer)
```

How can i set null value after validation after postback? Because script set 0 value to textbox after every postback?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.myclass').each(function () {
            this.value = this.value || "";
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you use the script above it will empty the textbox. Which probably will not get the `null` value, you want.

You should better disable it:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.myclass').each(function () {
           this.attr('disabled', true);
       });
   });
</script>
```